# Is there a way to get a short link to my Stack Overflow user profile?

Tags: support, s.tk, short-links

I've played around with the http://s.tk shortener, but I haven't figured out how to form a short link to my Stack Overflow user profile.  Is it possible?

Comment: I would like to see a `[user:name]` or `[user:id]` type of link, similar to tags. This would be great when referencing or quoting other users and their posts. Is this the correct place to post this or should I open a new topic for this?

Answer (score 90):

`s.tk` does not support any form of dynamic links like you're looking for.

The shortest option you have is `https://stackoverflow.com/u/YOUR_USER_ID`.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work. SO really needs a url shortening service like amazon or reddit.

Comment: @TravisHeeter [`http://stackoverflow.com/u/1152809`](http://stackoverflow.com/u/1152809) is what I meant.

Comment: Thankyou! now it fits in my resume!!
stackoverflow.com/u/8439576

Comment: I know this is a (very) old question, but you might try stackoverflow.name, too. My vanity URL is https://stackoverflow.name/sigpwned. Disclaimer: I'm the author!

Answer (score 16):

Stack Overflow now features Story, a nice way to show your CV.

To learn more go to:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/storypreferences
```

Your profile public link is customizable in this format:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/story/MY_USER_NAME
```

The traditional public link is this: `https://stackoverflow.com/cv/MY_USER_NAME`

Sadly, these two options don't have a link to your public profile, in that case, you need to use the classic:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/#####/your-name
```

Comment: This answer should be validated.

Comment: /story and /cv both not working for me. I wonder how this answer got upvotes

Comment: From the preferences page, just put in a username, and it would generate both cv and story URL

Comment: Both link, story and cv or not working

Comment: How can I get this SO image where my Name and reputation count is on? I see it quite ofteh with other websites linking to SE or SO.

Comment: Now that Careers is going away, none of the links except the last one ("the classic") will work.

Answer (score 8):

I've created [stk.so](https://stk.so/) — a tool that lets you create customizable, short URLs for Stack Overflow profiles.

(example: `https://stk.so/choraria` that would lead you to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/10713297/sourabh-choraria`)

Stack Apps' post for it can be found [here](https://stackapps.com/q/9335/89925). Figured I'll add some context on the **why** of it all :)

Comment: It stopped working...? The page loads but I can't authorize. It's stuck :C

Comment: @AgainPsychoX — I'm afraid so :( looks like an issue with the original SO JS SDK that I'm using with this project. More context can be found here — https://stackapps.com/questions/9335/customizable-short-urls-for-stack-overflow-profiles#comment18809_9335

Comment: @AgainPsychoX — just an FYI: I've reported this issue here — https://stackapps.com/questions/9455/issue-with-javascript-sdk

Comment: @AgainPsychoX — the issue has now been solved. Could you please try using [stk.so](https://stk.so/) again?

Comment: yeah, works :)  https://stk.so/AgainPsychoX

Comment: Great idea, but there are some issue, is the code open source ?

Answer (score 7):

http://s.tk cannot be used to link to profiles, it's mostly for short links to SE sites and some other SE pages. For a full list of available links, see [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk)

Answer (score 0):

I stood up `stackoverflow.name` to generate a vanity link for Stack Overflow profiles. For example, for my account, the generated link is:

```
https://stackoverflow.name/sigpwned
```

You can visit https://stackoverflow.name/ to set up your own link!

Comment: Re *"[stood up"*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stand_up#Verb): Not *"[put up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_up#Verb)"*?

Comment: [We like vanity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive)!

Comment: Re `https://stackoverflow.name/`: It is *[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/)*, not *StackOverflow*.

Comment: Would you be up for doing the same for stack exchange?

Comment: Boo to the people that downvoted this -- this is great!